# Ask for how to get user profile after callback

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ajax, ibm-cloud, single-sign-on

My web application is using Single Sign On (SSO) service from IBM Bluemix. This is the credentials info of my SSO service:

```
    {
   "SingleSignOn": [
     {
       "credentials": {
         "secret": "MYSECRET",
         "tokenEndpointUrl": "https://adminwebsso-jjjfvxi6wy-cq17.iam.ibmcloud.com/idaas/oidc/endpoint/default/token",
         "authorizationEndpointUrl": "https://adminwebsso-jjjfvxi6wy-cq17.iam.ibmcloud.com/idaas/oidc/endpoint/default/authorize",
         "issuerIdentifier": "adminwebsso-jjjfvxi6wy-cq17.iam.ibmcloud.com",
         "clientId": "MYCLIENTID",
         "serverSupportedScope": [
           "openid"
         ]
       },
       "syslog_drain_url": null,
       "volume_mounts": [],
       "label": "SingleSignOn",
       "provider": null,
       "plan": "professional",
       "name": "VA-Admin-Console-R1-SSO",
       "tags": [
         "security",
         "ibm_created",
         "ibm_dedicated_public"
       ]
     }
   ]
 }
```

From my Application, I redirect to Login page of IBM like URL:

```
https://adminwebsso-jjjfvxi6wy-cq17.iam.ibmcloud.com/idaas/oidc/endpoint/default/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=MYCLIENTID&redirect_uri=http://localhost/callback≻ope=openid%20openid
```

After login success IBM redirect to my web application, I can get parameter "code" from callback URL (http://localhost/callback?scope=openid&code=bngM6aV5cYHAvhv7wLAM5QSWFDARn7).

From there, I use the "code" to to get user profile. I have try to use AJAX to get user profile:

```
var settings = {
   "async": true,
   "crossDomain": true,
   "url": "https://idaas.ng.bluemix.net/sps/oauth20sp/oauth20/token",
   "method": "POST",
   "headers": {
     "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
     "authorization": "Basic RXhhbXBsZV9BcHBJRDpWUFlndEdXRlRvYVpZSUNTRzhJeVZFV000bUZicGpsU2t4RlRRbzlySkRGZDdzckc=",
     "cache-control": "no-cache"
   },
   "data": {
     "client_secret": "MYSECRET",
     "grant_type": "authorization_code",
     "redirect_uri": "http://localhost/callback",
     "code": "bngM6aV5cYHAvhv7wLAM5QSWFDARn7",
     "client_id": "MYCLIENTID"
   }
 }

 $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
   console.log(response);
 });
```

From ajax post above, I have tried to use the "code" from callback, but I've got an error message:

> 500 Error: Failed to establish a backside connection

I've got stuck here and don't know how to get user profile from SSO.

Comment: `"crossDomain": true` doesn't do what you think it does. Read the jQuery ajax docs. Probably it's not the issue here, but you should remove it anyway

Comment: But a 500 error is a server-side error. And the specific message suggests a fairly low-level network error. (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/IBM_DataPower_Gateways_Understanding_the_Failed_to_Establish_a_Backside_Connection_Error_Message?lang=en - first link on google to this error message, which also has some troubleshooting tips). So perhaps either a config error, or you need to raise a ticket with the server maintainer.

Comment: Sure, I have rised a ticket for them. But I do not sure https://idaas.ng.bluemix.net/sps/oauth20sp/oauth20/token still active or not. It has been three years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With in the SSO Service there are some inbuilt macros that can be used to get the user name, for more information please see.

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/SingleSignOn/customizing_pages.html#customizing_pages

@USERNAME@  The user ID of the authenticated user.